# GIT Private Repository - SSH Access to Sub Domain on MediaTemple.net

Tags: linux, ssh, git, mediatemple

I created a GIT Repository on one of my servers at MediaTemple.net the one I'm using is a (gs) Server. The repo was created on a subdomain (git.example.com)

I then created two user accounts with SSH enabled and FTP access to git.example.com

My problem is that when we login via SSH we end up in /home/00000/users/user%example.com/ and if we try to navigate to the domain/ folder we don't have access, so that is a good thing since I dont want to give users access to domain/ folder just the repository.

Now the question is how can I setup that when we login via SSH we end up in /home/00000/domains/git.example.com/repository ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The server administrator account is the only user on a grid server that has permissions to access outside a user directory.

from https://mediatemple.net/community/products/grid/204403684/connecting-via-ssh-to-your-server :

> Note:
>   This option enables SSH for the Server Administrator user only. This
>   is the only Grid SSH user with wide-reaching permissions.

It's my understanding that to add users that have broader access to SSH requires permissions to alter /etc/ssh/sshd_config, which the grid server administrator does not have permissions to, and so adding users with access outside their user directory does not seem possible.
https://www.ssh.com/ssh/sshd_config/

Alternatively you could forego http access and use a single ssh account as the repo location. the ssh login doesn't identify users, only allow blanket access to the repo. There are likely security pitfalls to this usage to think through.